# How can I reshape this DataFrame with Pivot function?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dataset, pivot

I work with this movies dataset containing following information:

```
df.head(10) 

color   director_name   num_critic_for_reviews  duration    director_facebook_likes actor_3_facebook_likes  actor_2_name    actor_1_facebook_likes  gross   genres  ... num_user_for_reviews    language    country content_rating  budget  title_year  actor_2_facebook_likes  imdb_score  aspect_ratio    movie_facebook_likes
0   Color   James Cameron   723.0   178.0   0.0 855.0   Joel David Moore    1000.0  760505847.0 Action|Adventure|Fantasy|Sci-Fi ... 3054.0  English USA PG-13   237000000.0 2009.0  936.0   7.9 1.78    33000
1   Color   Gore Verbinski  302.0   169.0   563.0   1000.0  Orlando Bloom   40000.0 309404152.0 Action|Adventure|Fantasy    ... 1238.0  English USA PG-13   300000000.0 2007.0  5000.0  7.1 2.35    0
2   Color   Sam Mendes  602.0   148.0   0.0 161.0   Rory Kinnear    11000.0 200074175.0 Action|Adventure|Thriller   ... 994.0   English UK  PG-13   245000000.0 2015.0  393.0   6.8 2.35    85000
3   Color   Christopher Nolan   813.0   164.0   22000.0 23000.0 Christian Bale  27000.0 448130642.0 Action|Thriller ... 2701.0  English USA PG-13   250000000.0 2012.0  23000.0 8.5 2.35    164000
4   NaN Doug Walker NaN NaN 131.0   NaN Rob Walker  131.0   NaN Documentary ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 12.0    7.1 NaN 0
5   Color   Andrew Stanton  462.0   132.0   475.0   530.0   Samantha Morton 640.0   73058679.0  Action|Adventure|Sci-Fi ... 738.0   English USA PG-13   263700000.0 2012.0  632.0   6.6 2.35    24000
6   Color   Sam Raimi   392.0   156.0   0.0 4000.0  James Franco    24000.0 336530303.0 Action|Adventure|Romance    ... 1902.0  English USA PG-13   258000000.0 2007.0  11000.0 6.2 2.35    0
7   Color   Nathan Greno    324.0   100.0   15.0    284.0   Donna Murphy    799.0   200807262.0 Adventure|Animation|Comedy|Family|Fantasy|Musi...   ... 387.0   English USA PG  260000000.0 2010.0  553.0   7.8 1.85    29000
8   Color   Joss Whedon 635.0   141.0   0.0 19000.0 Robert Downey Jr.   26000.0 458991599.0 Action|Adventure|Sci-Fi ... 1117.0  English USA PG-13   250000000.0 2015.0  21000.0 7.5 2.35    118000
9   Color   David Yates 375.0   153.0   282.0   10000.0 Daniel Radcliffe    25000.0 301956980.0 Adventure|Family|Fantasy|Mystery    ... 973.0   English UK  PG  250000000.0 2009.0  11000.0 7.5 2.35    10000
```

`df.columns`

```
Index(['color', 'director_name', 'num_critic_for_reviews', 'duration',
       'director_facebook_likes', 'actor_3_facebook_likes', 'actor_2_name',
       'actor_1_facebook_likes', 'gross', 'genres', 'actor_1_name',
       'movie_title', 'num_voted_users', 'cast_total_facebook_likes',
       'actor_3_name', 'facenumber_in_poster', 'plot_keywords',
       'movie_imdb_link', 'num_user_for_reviews', 'language', 'country',
       'content_rating', 'budget', 'title_year', 'actor_2_facebook_likes',
       'imdb_score', 'aspect_ratio', 'movie_facebook_likes'],
      dtype='object')
```

[Screenshot of the data (Notebook format)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qazSy.png)

I would like to reshape (not aggregate) this data with pivot function.

I have tried to do that with this code:

```
    pivoted = df.pivot( index= 'movie_title' , columns= [ 'director_name' , 'imdb_score' ] )
```

But i get this "ValueError":

```
 ValueError: all arrays must be same length
```

When I change the code to:

```
pivoted = df.pivot( index= 'movie_title' )
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError: cannot label index with a null key
```

What do I wrong here?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Further explanation:

> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in ()
>   ----> 1 pivoted = df.pivot( index= 'movie_title' , columns= [ 'director_name' , >'imdb_score' ] )
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in pivot(self, index, >columns, values)
>     4380         """
>     4381         from pandas.core.reshape.reshape import pivot
>   -> 4382         return pivot(self, index=index, columns=columns, values=values)
>     4383 
>     4384     _shared_docs['pivot_table'] = """
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\reshape.py in pivot(self, >index, columns, values)
>      378         cols = [columns] if index is None else [index, columns]
>      379         append = index is None
>   --> 380         indexed = self.set_index(cols, append=append)
>      381         return indexed.unstack(columns)
>      382     else:
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in set_index(self, keys, >drop, append, inplace, verify_integrity)
>     3150             arrays.append(level)
>     3151 
>   -> 3152         index = _ensure_index_from_sequences(arrays, names)
>     3153 
>     3154         if verify_integrity and not index.is_unique:
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in >_ensure_index_from_sequences(sequences, names)
>     4150         return Index(sequences[0], name=names)
>     4151     else:
>   -> 4152         return MultiIndex.from_arrays(sequences, names=names)
>     4153 
>     4154
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\multi.py in from_arrays(cls, >arrays, sortorder, names)
>     1144         for i in range(1, len(arrays)):
>     1145             if len(arrays[i]) != len(arrays[i - 1]):
>   -> 1146                 raise ValueError('all arrays must be same length')
>     1147 
>     1148         from pandas.core.categorical import _factorize_from_iterables
>
> ValueError: all arrays must be same length

Comment: I can't figure out how to post a DataFrame like that in a code format. How would you recommend to do this?

Comment: print `df.head(10)`, or even better `df[['insert', 'relevant', 'column', 'names', 'here']].head(10)`, and paste the output as text into your question, using the curly brace icon to format as code. also see how to create a [MCVE]

Comment: Okay but the output for head(10) looks like this:  color director_name num_critic_for_reviews duration director_facebook_likes actor_3_facebook_likes actor_2_name actor_1_facebook_likes gross genres ... num_user_for_reviews language country content_rating budget title_year actor_2_facebook_likes imdb_score aspect_ratio movie_facebook_likes
0 Color James Cameron 723.0 178.0 0.0 855.0 Joel David Moore 1000.0 760505847.0 Action|Adventure|Fantasy|Sci-Fi ... 3054.0 English USA PG-13 237000000.0 2009.0 936.0 7.9 1.78 33000
1 Color Gore Verbinski 302.0 169.0 563.0 1000.0 Orlando Bloom 40000.0 3090

Comment: @Patrick, it would help if you could edit the output of `df.head(10)` into your question. Comments strip out newlines. In the meantime, when you say "reshape (not aggregate)," what is your expected output? Something like `df.set_index('movie_title')[['director_name' , 'imdb_score']]`?

Comment: Please look at how to create a [MCVE], and reformat your question. It's best to have data to play with, and to know what is your expected output. Perhaps someone can answer your question without it, but you'll have better chances by providing a better example

Comment: Okay I reformated the question. Is that what you meant?

Comment: @Peter Leimbigler, my expected output is just to reshape the data to a  derivative DataFrame with index and columns categorized in a way that are more appropriate for further analysis

Comment: Better, I edited it a bit, but at least there is something for people to play with. Thanks!

Comment: Oh that looks nice, thanks!

Comment: @Patrick, specifically what index, columns, and cell values would your output contain? You may not need `pivot` if you don't plan to aggregate any values. Closer to your needs could be `pd.melt`.

Comment: Is pd.melt more common for reshaping a DataFrame than pivot() ? - I want "movie_title" as the index and the remaining elements as columns. But not all, there are some elements that I want to exclude. Thank you @Peter

Comment: @Patrick, `pd.melt` is an advanced method to reshape data (check out this guide: https://deparkes.co.uk/2016/10/28/reshape-pandas-data-with-melt/). For your purpose, I think all you need is this command from my earlier comment: `df.set_index('movie_title')[['director_name' , 'imdb_score']]`

Comment: @Patrick, were you able to solve this problem?